# How to pass an object that is a member of another object using JSON string notation?

Tags: c#, json

Well I have this class:

```
public class TAccount
{
    public Account account { set; get; }
    public double transactionAmount { set; get; }
}
```

And this class:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string AccountName { set; get; }
    public double Balance { set; get; }
    public string LastOperation { set; get; }

}
```

And I want to post the following [json](/questions/tagged/json)string but it can't see that I am trying to add values to the Account object inside `TAccount` class

[json](/questions/tagged/json)string:

```
{ "TransactionAmount": 98, "Account":[{"Id" : 4 , "LastOperation" : "credit"}]}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# Classes:

```
public class TAccount
{
    public Account account { get; set; }
    public double transactionAmount { get; set; }
}


public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public string LastOperation { get; set; }

}
```

Try sending with this structure:

```
{
    "transactionAmount": 98,
    "account": {
        "Id": 4,
        "LastOperation": "credit"
    }
}
```